# Can't activate A.N.T add-on, numpy error

Tags: python, error

This problem was happening since blender 2.78 of mine and I was hoping ping that from the >200 bug fixes mine would have been the one but unfortunately it's not a common bug. I can't activate A.N.T add-on and others that apparently are using the numpy module. In the python 3 console from my terminal I can easily important it with our an error but the blenders built-in console can't import it.

The error outputs the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 153, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: cannot import name 'multiarray'
```

Comment: [Blender comes with a bundled python version.  You can use your matching system version.](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_tips_and_tricks.html#bundled-python-extensions)  Which are you using?

Comment: The systems python3 works fine on importing the numpy module, I am currently using the blenders integrated python

Comment: In which case why not use system python with blender?, see link in comment above for howto's.  (It appears you are attempting to import system numpy going on paths in error)

Comment: I have done some digging and found that it's from the python version blender is currently using. numpy is not yet complied for python3.6 yet. Is there any way to make blender use python 3.4 with out breaking things.

Comment: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/` is certainly a system python path not a blender python path.  Is your system python 3.4?  In the blender python console, `import sys`  and paste the result of `sys.path` into your question (or somewhere).

Comment: As I stated before, my blender is running on python 3.6. The error is occurring because numpy is not working for python 3.6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78068/discussion-between-reuben-x-and-batfinger).